# Exclude all categories in failsafe

Tags: junit, junit4, maven-failsafe-plugin

I want to exclude those test classes which have ALL the categories mentioned in the  section of the failsafe configuration.

Presently, I believe it excludes all test classes which have any one of the categories mentioned in the  configuration.

> `<excludeGroups> Group1, Group2 </excludeGroups>`

```
@Categories(Group1.class)
public class SampleTest {
}
```

I want SampleTest to run with the mentioned configuration, but it is NOT running.